# Symfony share sessions betweens multiples apache aliases

Tags: php, apache, symfony, session

I have 2 symfony projects on the same website, simply by using aliases on apache. Example:

- `192.168.1.10/test1`
- `192.168.1.10/test2`

When I log into test1, I will be logged into test2. It's the same with log out.

Here is my code:

`App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator`:

```php
class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator {
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public function __construct(private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator) {}

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport {
        // all logins checks

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($username, function () use ($username) {
                return new MyUser($username);
            }),
            new CustomCredentials(function ($credentials, UserInterface $user) { return $user->getUserIdentifier() === $credentials; }, $username),
            [
                new RememberMeBadge() // pour le remember me
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('index'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate("login"); // direction le login
    }
}
```

`App\Security\UserProvider`:

```php
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
    
    public function loadUserByIdentifier($name): UserInterface {
        // never used
        return new MyUser($name);
    }

    function refreshUser($user): UserInterface {
        return $user;
    }

    function supportsClass(string $class): bool {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My firewall in `security.yaml`:

```yaml
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        user_provider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            entry_point: form_login
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%' # required
                lifetime: 604800
            logout:
                path: logout
            remote_user:
                provider: user_provider
```

Apache config:

```
Alias /test<id> /dir/to/test<id>/public

<Directory /dir/to/test<id>/public>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

(note:  is 1 or 2, and it's only for the example here)

How can I prevent the session to be the same for both alias?

Note: `test1` & `test2` doesn't have the same environment variables. Maybe it could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the save pathes of your sessions to different places inside your framework configuration

```
// config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
  session:
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native
```